# Html.ActionLink (): new { route value} is acting strangely. I don't know where length = 17 parameter is coming from

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I've this link on a page

```
<% = Html.ActionLink(item.Title, "Edit", "ArticleManagement", 
                      new { id = item.ArticleDataID })%>
```

and a simple method to receive the article Id

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
  //Do something
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting an error" **parameter dictionary contains a null value for parameter id of int32 for Edit(Int32)...**"

When I check the Url, I see something like "**http://localhost:59786/ArticleManagement/Edit?Length=17**"

What is "**Length=17**"? and what's doing there? Anyway, so far I'm working with a collection that has only 3 items on it.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to add null as the last parameter:

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("Title", "Edit", "ArticleManagement", 
        new { id = 1 }, new { @class = "link-class", attr = "attribute value" })%>
```

I think it uses you route values as html attributes without the null.

Comment: It make sense now. It's working now. So if I want to use both route valuees and html attributes, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen as well, it seems to happen when the actionlink can't match to a route.

Length 17 corresponds to the length of articlemanagement.

Edit: It might have something to do with the overload of ActionLink.